# Retrieve dataframe name from list of data frames while merging with reduce function

Tags: r, merge, reduce, names

I'm trying to merge together a list of data frames with the `reduce` function and I'm strugging with renaming the '.x' and '.y' endings for duplicate columns names with the names of the dataframes.

```
dat01_characterization<-data.frame(usubjid = as.factor(sample(10)), col2 = letters[1:10], col3 = letters[1:10])
dat02_consent<-data.frame(usubjid = as.factor(sample(10)), col3 = letters[1:10], col4 = letters[1:10])
dat03_psqi<-data.frame(usubjid = as.factor(sample(10)), col5 = letters[1:10], col3 = letters[1:10])

l2<-mget(ls(pattern="dat0"))
#l2<-list(dat01_characterization,dat02_consent,dat03_psqi)

mergefunction<-function(x,y){
  xname<-substr(names(x),regexpr("_",names(x))+1,nchar(names(x)))
  yname<-substr(names(y),regexpr("_",names(y))+1,nchar(names(y)))
  merged_data<-merge(x,y,by=c("usubjid"),all=TRUE)
  colnames(merged_data)<-gsub("\\.x",paste0("\\.",xname),names(merged_data))
  colnames(merged_data)<-gsub('\\.y',paste0("\\.",yname),names(merged_data))
  return(merged_data)
}
bbb<-Reduce(function(x,y) mergefunction(x,y),l2)
```

Using `names()` on the arguments in the reduce function will give me the columnnames of the dataframes as in using `names()` on a list object `l2[[1]]` rather than on the higher level object `l2[1]`. Any idea on how to access the actual dataframe names (i.e. dat01_characterization, etc.)

+++UPDATE+++

It didn't work with the original reduce function and I had to write my own version with a for loop. Here's how that works:

```
dat01_characterization2<-data.frame(usubjid = as.factor(sample(10)), col2 = letters[1:10], col3 = letters[1:10])
dat02_consent2<-data.frame(usubjid = as.factor(sample(10)), col3 = letters[1:10], col4 = letters[1:10])
dat03_psqi2<-data.frame(usubjid = as.factor(sample(10)), col5 = letters[1:10], col3 = letters[1:10])

l3<-mget(ls(pattern="dat0"))

out<-l3[[1]]
for(i in 2:length(l3)){
  yname<-substr(names(l3[i]),regexpr("_",names(l3[i]))+1,nchar(names(l3[i])))
  out<-merge(out,l3[[i]],by=c("usubjid"),all=TRUE)
  colnames(out)<-gsub("\\.x","",names(out))
  colnames(out)<-gsub('\\.y',paste0("\\.",yname),names(out))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dat01_characterization,dat02_consent,dat03_psqi are not data.frame names but names of variable containing the data.frame contents. Once you have evaluated your list into l2, evaluating each variable, the original names are lost. See str(l2)

Comment: Hi Nicholas2, you are right, the names are lost. However if I create the list with `l2<-mget(ls(pattern=past0("dat0")))` I can still retrieve the name by `l2[1]`. But how would I do this within the _reduce_ funtion? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can label the slots of the list this way (NB: paste0 is misspelled and unnecessary), but the reduce function only applies to the values of the slots of the list, it does : for (i in idx) {
    out <- .f(out, .x[[i]], ...)
  } where x[[i]] is the i-th slot value, while your l2[1] is still a list. You'd better rewrite your own version of reduce.

Comment: Yes, I had to write my own reduce function. Now it works. Thanks! I edited my initial question and put the solution up there.